# Opening an existing Django project with VS Code through Anaconda

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I installed Django and started a project via cmd yesterday. Today I installed Anaconda with VS Code and I now want to open my Django project in VS Code through Anaconda.

Is this possible? Id like Anaconda to be my interface for all my projects regardless of what they are. Is this possible?

thanks
V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I myself use Anaconda Environment in VSCode for Data Science Projects.
- For this, first you need to prepare a virtual env from Anaconda. Here is the tutorial for it in the official documentation : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments
  Follow this tutorial as it is without missing any line of code they ask you to.
- Once you are done setting it up. You just need to start your Django Project in VSCode.
- At the bottom where you see Python just click on it and Select Interpreter. From their, a list of virtual envs and Python envs opens up choose the one you created from Anaconda.
- You have anaconda libraries working in your project now.
- You can also start Jupyter notebook in VSCode : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_create-or-open-a-jupyter-notebook
- This way you can purely shift to VSCode for all of your stuff.
  Thank you